# complicated replace SQLITE Query

Tags: sqlite

The query should work on SQLITE MANAGER for Firefox:

The Problem, in side a row in one table of the database often is standing H(any numbers up to 9000) to times and it should only stand one time there. For example H6523H6523 and it should only stand H6523. This field is haveing a lot of text in, and inside this text the double H numbers are appearing.

The H6523 are also in another table in a seperate column. So it is possible to get the list after what must be looked.

- Table one is content, and the column in which it is wrong is data (long text)
- Table two is topics, and the column in which the H6523 is standing is subject. (only the H+number).

with the replace command it should work, but I would have to make a replace command for each H+number seperately.

So with triggers it should work.
But it does not work :(
The trigger step I set:

update content sET data=replace( (Select topics.sub2 From Topics), (select topics.subject from topics));

Comment: Do you have a coherent question? Questions end with the character `'?'`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, so it does not have much support program logic.

You have to write your replacement code in any other language that has better support for text processing.

Comment: Table: content
Row: Data (here a long text is standing and inside this text the H+number is appearing, and it can be that it is more often then one time appearing. But the Problem is, that often this H+number is two times behind each other, and it should be only one time.